# Slide a DIV up on load and down on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'd like my "newsbox" div to slide up from the bottom of the page to above my footer on page load (with a little delay) then I'd like the DIV to slide down if the user clicks on "newsClose". Tried something but without success (have no knowledge in js) - Thanks for your help

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7whAs/

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#newsbox').delay(2000).slideDown();
    jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('.newsClose').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        jQuery('#newsbox').slideUp();
    }); 
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="newsbox">
    <div class="news-text">
        <p>Blablablablabla blablabla blablabla <a href="index.html">Blabla blabla</a></p>
      </div>
    <div class="news-close">
        <a href="#" class="newsClose">Close X</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#newsbox {
    background-color: #CCC;
    display:none;
    width: 750px;
    z-index: 10000;
    float: left;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 45px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

.news-text {
    float: left;
    width: 600px;

}
.news-text p {
    color: #666666;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 13px;
}
.news-continue {
    float: left;
    width: 70px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
.news-close {
    width: 60px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
.news-close a,
.news-text a {
    color: #3E718E;
}
.news-continue a,
.news-close a {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 11px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #FFF;
    display: block;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    background-color: #3E718E;
}

.news-close a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.news-continue a:hover,
.news-close a:hover {
    background-color: #333333;
    color: #FFF;
}

.news-close {
    float: right;
    width: 60px;
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 11px;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were close. First enable jQuery on your fiddle (it's on the left side), then eliminate your second DOM ready function:

Demo    http://jsfiddle.net/7whAs/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#newsbox').delay(2000).slideDown();
    jQuery('.newsClose').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        jQuery('#newsbox').slideUp();
    }); 
});
```

Comment: also if you decide to work with the shorthand '$' for jQuery (which should be fine), you can stick with it in the rest of your code (replace jQuery by $), but that is just esthetics.